# Verifying message authenticity with RSA

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I have JSON data coming from my server that I would like to verify on my client. The data I want to transmit is just a boolean, but I have included a uuid to be part of the hash.

Here is an example of a message from the server:

```
response = {
    "encrypted": "kgbh6RN2XRHAU1QyjEJXqkr5DmNpnkaS/bdNG7nKoLBCK8V4xzv12ScMii8GJEgpNYbY5oH2gtGBgZxDo3DwkRmzFdomUkDDbpospomTRRCdU7bko8/Ix0MFvm9Dwh6KG3D4AIBW36O9RJ95WsErwox4fwMRR7Qes/anS9dVoVh5nswtyjAjtrDB+dCgTfFbOCqx/cZHpWJWUJ8Rv4Sx/oN+tAOw2ibU4SiLlsF/YYqkesk6spHwB9ud/4kZc8Xfb+QV6t31xZPXwjCgvrySiv/bgGyZl4irPihBAtoD3sM/QEwVpPsUs2zKqALR8rD6LwBUa5gAVrnGU++5kV6RoA==",
    "message_id": "203e4e58-30cf-11ea-8f5b-7085c257599e",
    "valid": False
}
```

`"encrypted"` is generated as follows:

```
import uuid
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import hashlib
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
import base64


message_id = uuid.uuid1()
with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key_file.read(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )
message = bytes(hashlib.sha3_256((str(message_id) + str(valid)).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), "utf-8")
encrypted_data = public_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
encrypted_data = str(base64.b64encode(encrypted_data), "utf-8")
```

Then on the client, I want to hash together `"message_id"` and `"valid"` and if the message came from me then the result should be the same as `"encrypted"` decrypted. So I tried that:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import hashlib
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
import base64

encrypted = response["encrypted"]
message_id = response["message_id"]
valid = response["valid"]
with open("private_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted)
decrypted = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
new_hash = bytes(hashlib.sha3_256((str(message_id) + str(valid)).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), "utf-8")
if new_hash == decrypted:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

My problem is that this prints "No", and the code is very messy. Especially with all the encodes and decodes and converting strings to byte objects etc.

Can someone help me fix this code please?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

My code is now producing "Yes". However, I don't think it's very clean and I would like to improve it. What would you suggest?

Comment: If your code runs you can ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com; note that you might want to give a better description for it than "my code is messy" - what in particular are you not happy about?

Comment: Maarten is right - code review is the place to go if your code works.